# Video capturing(live video streaming) through Java

Tags: video-streaming, video-capture, live-streaming

I want to write a program that can capture video through my webcam by using Java language, i.e live video streaming.
I have found some threads about this topic but the issue is how can i make my program Operating system independent, like how to capture video on 32 bit and 64bit operating systems..

Kindly help me to solve this, i have very short time for this job. Also if anybody have some lead to this topic, post its link here..
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. As there are no classes in j2se that can be used to capture video from a webcam, so you need an external library like JMF or JavaCV, to do the same.
2. To install JavaCV you will find instructions on these links:

   a. ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in [Link](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in/2011/12/opencv-javacv-eclipse-project.html)

   b. code.google.com [Link](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/)
3. The code to capture video in real time from camera:

   ```
   import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
   import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvFlip;

   class GrabberShow implements Runnable 
   {    
      IplImage image;
      CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");
      public GrabberShow() {
          canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      }
      @Override
      public void run() {
          FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0); // 1 for next camera
          try {
              grabber.start();
              IplImage img;
              while (true) {
                  img = grabber.grab();
                  if (img != null) {
                      cvFlip(img, img, 1);// l-r = 90_degrees_steps_anti_clockwise
                      canvas.showImage(img);
                  }
              } 
          } catch (Exception e) {}
      }
   }

   public class Main 
   {
          public static void main(String[] args) 
          {
              GrabberShow gs = new GrabberShow();
              Thread th = new Thread(gs);
              th.start();
          }
   }
   ```

hope this helps.